# how to downgrade moto g 2nd gen from lollipop to kitkat without root

Tags: downgrade

I am having a problem while gaming on my new android update on moto g (2nd gen). So, i want to downgrade the android version please help me out.

Comment: Related, but not duplicate as the nexus devices have "factory images": [Can I downgrade to an earlier version of Android after installing an OTA update?](/questions/57792/can-i-downgrade-to-an-earlier-version-of-android-after-installing-an-ota-update)

Answer (score 1):

A downgrade (as well as an upgrade) can be performed by flashing the corresponding ROM that match your device configuration, that is  MOTO-G (2nd Gen.)

So, first thing is to find Appropriate ROM for your device MOTO-G.(2nd Gen.)
You may find more hints at this [LINK](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device).

Once you find the ROM, you can downgrade(or upgrade), as needed.
 Refer [rom-flashing](/questions/tagged/rom-flashing) for more details and instructions related to ROM Flashing.